# How to Color CLion Console Output with C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When using `Code Blocks` I used the following code to color my console output.

```
void Col(enum Color ChosenColor)
{
    HANDLE  hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, ChosenColor);
    return;
}
```

But this no longer plays an effect on the same code but within `CLion`. Why, and what, if any, alternatives do I have to replicating the desired effect?
For my class I'm required to make games for practice using ASCII characters within the console window. A game without colors is awful.

Comment: Does this code work correctly when it is running in a separate console/command window?

Comment: How about using normal escape sequences? http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting Also, this has nothing to do with CLion, as you're using win32 apis.

Comment: I'm confused. How is an IDE supposed to change the behavior of the Windows API? The conclusions you draw from your observations are ill-guided, and this question is based on unfounded assumptions, making it somewhat useless.